# I don’t know what’s happening with my cacti it had brown spots on it and it happens a week ago I think

Tags: diagnosis, cactus

[image] so I don’t know what’s wrong with my cacti

Comment: That's two cactus grafted together; one is a Hylocereus (the green bottom part) and the orange/red part is a Gymnocalycium mihanovichii. The top part relies on the bottom part for nutrition. Is it getting more spots, or does it still look the same? From the picture it's hard to tell what's causing it. If you could get a better picture of the brown spots it will help. Did anything change about it's care? More/less sun, temperature, fertilizer, insect attack, overwatering. The bottom shouldn't be as sensitive to overwatering as most cactus. Other than the spots it looks pretty good.